# gradle-witness checksum fail after generation

Tags: android, gradle

I am having a strange gradle-witness problem after the androidx migration. When running the calculateChecksums gradle task it generates the following entry:

'com.google.auto:jetified-auto-common-0.10:0.10:jetified-auto-common-0.10.jar:d8f8dce3d48dbcf3d597fef59d254b5f72a956ad37c95d9ed4406526b9f31a27',

but when verifying dependencies it then fails with:

```
> Checksum failed for com.google.auto:jetified-auto-common-0.10:0.10:jetified-auto-common-0.10.jar:545298d953773565d49ddaac25ea91b6c22adab122fa2c6461aa371ad91dcb02
```

Does anyone have some idea why the verification fails for this artifact?

If someone wants to try it out - it is in the migrate_androidx task in WallETH https://github.com/walleth/walleth

Comment: Came back to this after a while and digged deeper: I think the root cause of the problem is the jetifier manipulating jars in a non-deterministic way - some more details here: https://github.com/walleth/walleth/issues/354